# Is there any way to do flutter and twilio chat?

Tags: flutter, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Flutter and Twilio chat integration?
Twilio released separately android and ios. any other alternative is there for Flutter?

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_chat

Comment: This package is currently work-in-progress and should not be used for production apps. We can't guarantee that the current API implementation will stay the same between versions, until we have reached v1.0.0.

Comment: Or you can use https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_flutter

Comment: Thanks@AVEbrahimi A Package that helps with twilio API.Currenty supports only sms sending functionality.With time more features will be released.i want Twilio chat.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Just to let you know, [Twilio Programmable Chat will be sunsetted on July 25th 2022](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/programmable-chat-end-of-life), so we don't recommend building new applications with Chat.

However, [Programmable Chat will be replaced by Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/migrating-chat-conversations).

There is not a Flutter library that implements Twilio Conversations, that I am aware of, but you should look for or build a library that works with Conversations so that you future proof your application.